# Use git as a diff only

Tags: git, compare, branch, diff, history

Because of (insert-valid-reason-here) i need to upload a set of files to GIT. These files are uploaded to a specific repo named after the machine where the files are took from. I want to enable the ability to compare differences between branches. (which represent each machine)

To clarify: it is ONE repository, where each branch represents each machine.

So, each week a snapshot of some files will be uploaded to the proper branch, and then i need to compare them to see what has changed.

Right now, i am creating the branches and then upload (push) the changes to GIT successfully. However, when i want to compare between them, i can not do it because it complains about the branches having a different history.

I am still not able to figure out how to make this work on git. Rebase --onto does not work ok, and i need a general idea on how could i do this.

Comment: So which is it, multiple repositories with one per machine, or a single repository with multiple branches, one per machine?

Comment: A single repository. with one branch per machine.

Comment: How did you create the branches in the first place, such that they don't have any common history?

Comment: Actually, that is the purpose of the question. What should be the process that ensures that the branches have all a common history to they can be compared from now on?

Comment: You can't create a branch until you have at least one commit. So what was in the initial commit that allowed you to create a new branch?

Comment: I had only a README.md on master. Then the other branches started with all the file contents.